# firemonkey enablecontrols/disablecontrols with grid

Tags: delphi, grid, firemonkey

I recently moved to firemonkey framework programming and I am facing a strange behavior with grid and disablecontrols and enablecontrols.

As i should i call clientdataset.disablecontrols, before clientdataset update, in order to avoid display to the grid and speedup the operation. Finally i call enablecontrols in order to update the grid.

My problem is that after enablecontrols call the grid is not properly refreshed. Either i miss records either i miss data. But only the display is wrong. The underlying data are correct. I checked with the debuger.

I can force the update of the grid by update something in the clientdataset (without disablecontrols/enablecontrols) but i don't think this is the proper way.

Is this a bug or am i missing something with firemonkey?

Answer (score 1):

In Firemonkey please use next code:

```
Grid1.BeginUpdate 
try
  // creating rows in Grid
finally
  Grid1.EndUpdate;
end;
```